# Group arrays by linear comparison

Tags: javascript, data-structures, underscore.js

```
var data = [[1, 4], [8, 10], [12, 14]]
var line = data[i];
```

I start to draw line, `x1 = line[0] to x2 = line[1]` at `y=10`

This is x  axis with set of lines drawn

`0 ' ' 3 ' ' 6 ' ' 9 ' ' 12 ' '  15`

```
  -------       -----    -----
```

**when data changes:**
`var data = [[1, 4], [3, 7], [8, 10], [12, 14]]`

`0 ' ' 3 ' ' 6 ' ' 9 ' ' 12 ' '  15`

```
  -------       -----    -----
      --------
```

since `l1 = [1, 4]` is drawn under `l2 = [3, 7] // if(l2[0] < l1[1]) somehow need to y+=10 //`

**changes again:**
`var data = [[1, 4], [3, 7], [2, 5], [8, 10], [12, 14]]`

`0 ' ' 3 ' ' 6 ' ' 9 ' ' 12 ' '  15`

```
  -------       -----    -----
      --------
    -------
```

`y+=20`

`var lines = [[line, line, line], [line], [line]]`

Can someone restructure `data` into `lines` with sets of `line` for offsetting `y value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive function which tests for "overlaps" like this

```
function organise(data1) {
    var data2 = [[]], moreWorkNeeded = [],
        i = data1.length, j;
    d1: while (i-->0) { // loop down, later nodes come last
        for (j = 0; j < i; ++j) { // loop up, stop at current
            if (
                    (data1[i][0] >= data1[j][0] && data1[i][0] <= data1[j][1])
                    ||
                    (data1[i][1] >= data1[j][0] && data1[i][1] <= data1[j][1])
                ) {
                    moreWorkNeeded.push(data1[i]);
                    continue d1;
            }
        }
        data2[0].push(data1[i]);
    }
    if (moreWorkNeeded.length)
        data2 = data2.concat(organise(moreWorkNeeded.reverse())); // recurse
    return data2;
}
```

now every time there is an overlap, the following items get pushed down into the next level

```
var data = [[1, 4], [3, 7], [2, 5], [8, 10], [12, 14]];
organise(data);
/* [
    [[12, 14], [8, 10], [1, 4]],
    [[3, 7]],
    [[2, 5]]
]*/
```